# RegQueryValueEx записывает в буфет только 1 байт

Tags: c++, winapi

```
HKEY hKey;
char keyData[256] = { 0 };
DWORD keysize = sizeof(keyData);
if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"Software\\hrz", 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    if (RegQueryValueEx(hKey, L"Key", NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)keyData, &keysize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
      cout << keyData;
    }
}
RegCloseKey(hKey);
```

Почему в keyData записывается только первый байт того что должно быть?Я знаю, что вместо типа char должен быть wchar_t,но ведь LPBYTE это указатель на байт,а char это как раз байт.А wchar_t это 2 байта,но с wchar_t работает, а с char нет...

Comment: А чему равен `keysize` после выполнения функции `RegQueryValueEx`?

Comment: keysize в 2 раза больше чем должен быть,т есть "ukk" это 8 байт а не 4

Comment: Пока разбирался,понял что существует 2 версии RegOpenKeyEx,для юникода и ANSI и они по разному пишут в буфер,от этого и моя проблема

Comment: Если Вы сделаете вывод через `std::wcout`, как предложил Alex F, скорее всего обнаружите, что в буфере лежит именно то, что Вы хотели. Когда Вы делаете вывод через `std::cout` он обнаруживает ноль (а он там обязательно появится: char 'u' -> wchar_t ['u', '0', '0', '0']), и на этом вывод прекращается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я разобрался,существует 2 версии `RegOpenKeyEx`:`RegOpenKeyExA` и `RegOpenKeyExW` которые выбираются в зависимости от настроек проекта.Я использовал настройку проекта для UNICODE и использовал буфер типа `char`,в который писалось не по 1 байту а по 2(тип wchar_t).